# How to estimate the file size of a video in a particular resolution?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, h.264, filesize

I'm trying to develop a video compressor where I have to estimate the file size before compression based on different resolutions.

For encoding I am using H264 codec. And I have no idea how it compress the video.

```
I'm looking forward to something like this. 
1440*720 - estimated file size : 6.2mb - 75%
960*480  - estimated file size : 2.9mb - 37%
480*240  - estimated file size : 857kb - 25%
```

Answer (score 3):

You can’t . File size is a function of bitrate, and is resolution independent. You can have a 1080p 30 second file be 2 megabytes, or 200 megabytes depending on the complexity of the content and quality you wish to achieve.